# Strange events in windows 10 event log regarding the Windows Modules installer service

Tags: windows-10, event-viewer

I was just looking through my event viewer because I have a device that keeps disconnecting and reconnecting, so I was trying to find out if it was a software issue, or if maybe a wire in a USB cable got messed up, and I came across some really strange entries. This is on a Windows 10 Home 64 bit system

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2024-02-16 11:31:38 AM
Event ID:      7040
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-CA9265O
Description:
The start type of the Windows Modules Installer service was changed from auto start to demand start.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7040</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-16T16:31:38.9786775Z" />
    <EventRecordID>100903</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="996" ThreadID="20380" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-CA9265O</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Windows Modules Installer</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">auto start</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">demand start</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">TrustedInstaller</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2024-02-16 11:12:44 AM
Event ID:      7040
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-CA9265O
Description:
The start type of the Windows Modules Installer service was changed from demand start to auto start.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7040</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-16T16:12:44.2737181Z" />
    <EventRecordID>100902</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="996" ThreadID="16768" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-CA9265O</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Windows Modules Installer</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">demand start</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">auto start</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">TrustedInstaller</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2024-02-16 11:12:40 AM
Event ID:      7040
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-CA9265O
Description:
The start type of the Windows Modules Installer service was changed from auto start to demand start.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7040</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-16T16:12:40.0349188Z" />
    <EventRecordID>100901</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="996" ThreadID="16768" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-CA9265O</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Windows Modules Installer</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">auto start</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">demand start</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">TrustedInstaller</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          2024-02-16 10:57:11 AM
Event ID:      7040
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-CA9265O
Description:
The start type of the Windows Modules Installer service was changed from demand start to auto start.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7040</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-02-16T15:57:11.2390014Z" />
    <EventRecordID>100900</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="996" ThreadID="15748" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-CA9265O</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Windows Modules Installer</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">demand start</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">auto start</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">TrustedInstaller</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Can anyone think of any logical reason why the trusted installer would change its start type from demand start to auto start, then 15 minutes later, change it back to demand start, then another 4 seconds later, change back to auto start, and then another 18 minutes later switch back to demand start? Maybe I'm just paranoid, but something seems really off here.....

Answer (score 0):

This is **normal** behavior of Windows, and is kicked off by the Windows Update processes when it needs to check for/download/install updates. Not related to USB devices, unless Windows is trying to re-install new drivers for it from windows update constantly (which you would see in the System log as well).

You may also see the same 7040 events for the "Background Intelligent Transfer Service" (BITS) changing its startup mode for example.